# Dell g15 5520 laptop can not connect to external monitor

Tags: 20.04, external-monitor

I have a dell G15 5520 laptop running ubuntu 20.04 and I have a problem connecting an external monitor(DELL).
Bios version: 1.13.2
What should I do?
I tried:
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall ,then reboot
I also tried to disable secure boot (and now is disabled) ,but didnt work...

Comment: So, what happens when you connect the external monitor? Did you try connecting the same laptop to another monitor/connecting the monitor to another computer?

Comment: My external monitor works fine with my other laptop running the same OS. So the problem is no about the monitor.
When I connect the G15 5520 to monitor ,nothing happens

Comment: Did you try connecting via both VGA and HDMI (if both of them are available)? What exactly happens when you connect the external monitor?

Comment: I tried only with hdmi. Well, as I said when I connect the hdmi to external monitor, the monitor is just black...It's like it is not connected.What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I changed a driver from "software and updates" and no the external monitor works as I expected.